# Prevent object from "jumping" in video

Tags: matlab

I want to make a video with Matlab using the VideoWriter class. I have several frames of an object as single point clouds and I want to put the frames one after another into my video. As for now, I am doing this like this:

```
function [] = makeMyVideo(videoPath, framerate, filenamestoplot)

writerObj = VideoWriter(videoPath);
writerObj.FrameRate = framerate;
open(writerObj);


figure;ptHandles = onePlot(filenamestoplot);axis off;view(54,12);
axis tight
set(gca,'nextplot','add');
set(gcf,'Renderer','zbuffer');
firstCameraPos = campos;
for k = 1:numel(filenamestoplot)
   pause(0.1);
   delete(ptHandles);
   ptHandles = onePlot(filenamestoplot(k));axis off;view(54,12);
   campos(firstCameraPos);
   frame = getframe(gcf);
   writeVideo(writerObj,frame);
end

close(writerObj);

end
```

This works, but my 3D object is "making little jumps". I tried to fix this by setting the camera position for every frame, but unfortunately this did not solve the problem. Do you have any idea, how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what you are plotting but it's probably axis limits or similar which are not set equally. Could you provide a complete example which allows to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Now tried to set xlim to the value of the first frame for every following frame, behavior is the same. For a complete example I would have to give you the data I want to plot - I suppose I could upload part of it. What is the common way of doing this within stackoverflow?

Comment: I fixed it. I only set the xlim, now that I set xlim, ylim and zlim it works. Thanks for the hint! I however do not quite understand why the limits move in the first place...